# PhoneGap send data C#

Tags: c#, html, cordova

There is a project Mobile application and this app communicate with the existing writed C# server. 
How to efficient way to comminicate with PhoneGap and C# server application.?

Comment: What output format does your existing C# server provide? If it's a web service you can simply open a XMLHttpRequest in PhoneGap, like you would do in a regular web site.

Comment: an alternative to Ajax can be WebSockets: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: WebSockets are not the way to go here ... There are simpler and more secure methods. Ajax being the most apt.

Comment: If you need Websockets, use SignalR http://signalr.net/ then you have fallback if they're not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend ASP.NET MVC and return JSON Data.

Good sample: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETMakingJSONWebAPIsWithASPNETMVC4BetaAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx